# Confusing about mysql, java date and timezone

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, datetime

Considering the follow entity:

```
Java : Message (Date registrationDate, Date deliveryDate, Date scheduleDate)
Mysql: message (registration_date datetime, delivery_date datetime, schedule_date date)
```

Let's suppose that:

```
registrationDate = '2014-03-17 20:00:00'  
deliveryDate = '2014-03-17 20:00:00'  
scheduleDate = '2014-03-17 20:00:00'
```

I'm trying to understand why i'm getting a wrong date in the follow scenario using Hibernate and mysql:
**1º Stores a date using &useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC connection string:**
- registration_date = '2014-03-17 **23**:00:00' (OK in UTC)
- delivery_date = '2014-03-17 **23**:00:00' (OK in UTC)
- schedule_date date = '2014-03-**17**' (OK in UTC)

**2º Retrieves the entity and shows in view (GMT-3):**
- registrationDdate = '2014-03-17 **20**:00:00' (OK)
- deliveryDdate = '2014-03-17 **20**:00:00' (OK)
- scheduleDdate = '2014-03-**16**' (NOT OK, 2014-03-17 00:00:00 - 03:00 = 16/03/2014 21:00:00)

I know that when Date.toString is called, it's getting the local timezone, but how to avoid this behavior ? I'm storing this values correctly ?

The hour initially was 17, i need to retrieve with 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems both your App Server and MySQL have a difference of 3 hours w.r.t. UTC.

Set the TimeZone to UTC and then retreive.

**Example**:

```
TimeZone.setDefault( TimeZone.getTimezone( "UTC" ) );
scheduleDdate = rs.getDate( "scheduleDdate" );
```

**Other Examples**:

```
System.out.println( TimeZone.getDefault() );
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d = cal.getTime();
System.out.println( " d: " + d );
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-3"));
System.out.println( " d(GMT-3): " + d );
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println( " d(GMT)  : " + d );
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println( " d(UTC)  : " + d );
```

**Results**:

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="IST",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,
                    useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]
 d: Tue Mar 18 06:41:52 IST 2014
 d(GMT-3): Mon Mar 17 22:11:52 GMT-03:00 2014
 d(GMT)  : Tue Mar 18 01:11:52 GMT 2014
 d(UTC)  : Tue Mar 18 01:11:52 UTC 2014
```

Comment: OK, my app server and mysql now have no difference.
My mistake now is on my JSF view because i'm using f:convertDateTime with timezone='GMT-3' to shows only dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the MySQL JDBC driver (including the latest 5.1.29 version) in handling timezones and DATE (not DATETIME) columns:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71084

The workaround suggested in the bug report is adding "useServerPrepStmts=true".